# Make a list of certain classes within a module

Tags: python, class, module

I have a module `M` which has a couple of classes in it. I want to make a list of all classes in this module of which instances have `addToList` attribute set to `True`. I tried fiddling with `vars(M)` and `dir(M)` functions but I don't really know what to loop over and how to get this attribute's value...

Of course, I'm making this list outside the module, e.i. the module is imported.

Here's an example of the module I'm thinking about:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.addToList = True
    #more stuff here...
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.addToList = True
class C():
    def __init__(self):
        self.addToList = False
```

I can also make a superclass that will have `addToList` set to True, and then make `A` and `B` inherit from it, if that would help.

Comment: You've an instance attribute here, not class attribute.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary doh, you're right. Still, my question remains. I think I can change it to class attribute if that'll make things simpler. It probably will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from types import ClassType

import classes  # Your module containing the classes

out = []

# or you can also iterate over just vars(classes).values() as you only need the
# objects not their name.   
for k, v in  vars(classes).items():
    if isinstance(v, ClassType):
        if getattr(v, 'addToList', None) or getattr(v(), 'addToList', None):
            out.append(v)
print out
#[<class classes.A at 0x0000000002B7CCA8>, <class classes.B at 0x0000000002B7CD68>]
```

Comment: yes it works, and yes I'll just iterate over `values()`. Thanks!